# Error in my calling Function

Tags: c#

this is my code

```
public delegate void NotifyFunc(enumType notificationType, IntPtr data); 

[DllImport("VssSdkd")] 
public static extern void startVssSdkClientEcho(string IpAddress, 
    long port, NotifyFunc notifyFunc, eProtocolType proType, bool Req);
```

am call the function like

```
CallBack calbck = new CallBack(TestDllImport.Callbackas);

startVssSdkClientEcho("192.168.10.240", 12050, calbck, TestDllImport.eProtocolType.eProtocolType_VssSdk, false);
```

here my receving callback function is

```
static public void Callbackas(eNotificationType type, IntPtr datas) {}
```

here first time am receving data and then it's giving Error msg like :

```
run time check failure #0 - the value if ESP was not properly saved across a function call.
 this is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention 
with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention
```

please help me to identify my error... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this your code you are calling (sorry cursory search could only find your other post referring to startVssSdkClientEcho). Is it decalred cdecl (i.e. it has no __declspec at all) or is it stdcall. If it is cdecl you need to add CallingConvention attribute to the DllImport

i.e.

```
[DllImport("VssSdkd", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Of course it might also be the callback calling convention at fault which is another issue.