# Is it possible to use win32 DLLs in C#?

Tags: c#

I have win32 DLL named VssSdkd.dll. It contains two classes with names VssSdkServiceLogin and VssSdkMsg.

I need to import the VssDskServiceLogin class, in C#. I am setting few properties of **VssDskServiceLogin** object and passing this to **VssSdkMsg** which in turn invokes some other method.

How can I achieve this using C#.

Comment: It would be better to put a little more detail into your question title: "Is't possible in C#" is just too vague. I'll fix the spelling for you.

Comment: You have a very similar question here (2 hours apart): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653526/error-in-my-calling-function maybe give people a chance to answer and accept once in a while

Answer (score 6):

> I have win32 DLL named VssSdkd.dll. It
>   contains two classes with names
>   VssSdkServiceLogin and VssSdkMsg.
>
> In C#, I need to import the
>   VssDskServiceLogin class. In the class
>   are some attributes I need to set the
>   value for, sending the information to
>   VssSdkMsg and call another function
>
> I need to achieve those things through
>   C# code. Is this possible, and if so,
>   how?

Classes compiled in C++ (and other Win32 languages) cannot be interoped with Dot NET languages.  Structures may be if care is taken.  Dot NET does have support for COM objects, though.

Native  functions may be called from Dot NET languages if they're tagged with the `[DllImport]` attribute on the CLR side (and the appropriate `DllImportAttribute` properties are set) - and exported on the Win32 side.  However, this is a non-trivial process.  I would recommend grabbing a good book on the subject and starting from the top.  SO is probably not a very good medium for addressing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with p/invoke and marshaling. Read about it, it's too complicated a subject to explain fully in a SO answer.

Comment: all the examples you'll need : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx

Comment: @JimSchubert the above link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is sometimes possible in C# through P/Invoke, but when dealing with classes, this can get very, very difficult.

I'd highly recommend creating a C# wrapper for your DLL using Managed C++ instead.

Comment: Google some examples for Managed C++. Essentially, you import your DLL exactly the same as if you were using it in C++ (likely what it was made for). When defining your class in C++ though, you use the `ref` keyword to signal that you're making a .NET class, allowing you to use it in C#. It's far too much to explain on here, it'll take some learning but I think you'd run into less issues in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/unmanaged_to_managed.aspx) will solve your problem directly, but I expect you can find a good example of how to do this at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com).  Managed C++ can be a little tricky until you get used to it, and I think the syntax changed from .NET 1.0/1.1 to .NET 2.0.  Make sure you know what version of .NET you're targeting and search the [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) site accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you are looking for is interoperability with COM. 
I haven't worked much on it, but can give you a sample code to start with.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String
text, String caption, uint type);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello, world!", "My box", 0);
}
```

This may be of help.

Comment: Your sample has nothing to do with COM interop. It shows a sample of P/Invoke (that will not work, by the way, since the `DllImport` declares a method called `MessageBox` and your code sample invokes a method called `ShowBox`).

Comment: Sorry, Edited. i meant to call Messagebox